# Iterate through dataframe to obtain a desired result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has 3 fields

```
date_1, date_2, num_Days
```

`num_Days` is a derived column which is calculated by `date_2 - date_1`

I want to bring the `num_Days` in the range of 1-30. Currently it takes on more values than that.

For the following I wanted to iterate through the dataframe and change the `date_2` where the `num_Days` value is greater than 30 using a random delta value.

I have been trying this using the following function:

```
date_format = '%d/%m/%y' 

def gen_by_delta(src_dates, num_days, date_format, delta_min, delta_max):
    gen_dates = []

    for dt in src_dates:
        src_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, date_format)

        if src_date is None:
            gen_dates.append("")
            continue

        for d in num_days:

            if d > 30 :
                chosen_delta = pick_random_delta_in_range(min_days=delta_min, max_days=delta_max)
                result_date = (src_date + chosen_delta).strftime(date_format)
                gen_dates.append(result_date)

    return gen_dates
```

Using this function is giving me the error:

```
> data_string[found.end():])
> 
> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 19
```

Is there something that I am missing, or any other better way to achieve the same?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When working with Pandas it's usually best to think of everything as vectorized operations. So let's start by generating a series of random deltas in the range of `delta_min` to `delta_max` inclusive, assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
rand_days = np.random.randint(delta_min, 1+delta_max, len(df))
rand_deltas = pd.to_timedelta(rand_days, unit="d")
```

Then we want to replace columns `date2` and `num_Days` with this whenever `date2 - date1` is outside of our range:

```
outside_range = df["date2"] - df["date1"] > pd.Timedelta(days=delta_max)
df["date2"][outside_range] = df["date1"][outside_range] + rand_deltas[outside_range]
df["num_Days"][outside_range] = rand_deltas[outside_range]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, However I am getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' `. I am not sure of the reason as it is not taking the date. Can you please help

Comment: @vp7 You need to convert the date columns from strings to actual timestamps with `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: I did the same and now I am getting `TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`